# Celery workers cannot access the database

Tags: django, celery, django-orm, django-celery

I am running the latest stable version of Celery and django-celery. I have defined a task which is passed a primary key, gets the object associated with that key, and processes it. This all works well when I call the function directly, but when I put the message in the queue (MongoDB), the workers fail (with the attached stacktrace) when accessing the database. Has anyone else run into this problem?

```
[2012-05-04 12:01:23,673: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: app.tasks.process_model[71934fab-b3a2-4847-bb3e-00484d77c6c7]
[2012-05-04 12:01:25,202: INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[2012-05-04 12:01:35,618: ERROR/MainProcess] Task coupons.tasks.queue_print_image[71934fab-b3a2-4847-bb3e-00484d77c6c7] raised exception: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user>/Envs/cf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 634, in _join_exited_workers
    raise WorkerLostError("Worker exited prematurely.")
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely.
```

Comment: OSX Lion. I've discovered it happens when using SQLite, but works using MySQL. I'm just using MySQL for now.